# Function Optimization

Tags: nonlinear-optimization

Assume any recursive function like:  (just for example, my rekursive function is just too big to write)
$x_{n+1}=\frac{(x_{n}-3)^{5}x_{n}^{2}}{a\sqrt{x_{n}}}$
(or any other non-linear function)

Is there any optimization-algorithm, which allows me to find the optimal value for $a$ if I want to find the Mimimum of
$x_{n+1}=\frac{(x_{n}-3)^{5}x_{n}^{2}}{a\sqrt{x_{n}}}$  for a fixed $x_{0}$?

Comment: How do you know if this minimum exists?

Comment: i don't understand the sence of this question

Comment: @SergioParreiras: Yes, the maximum exist for my problem exists definitely

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner The sense is, if there are any optimization algorithms or other methods for non-linear rekursive functions.

Comment: introduce $x_1, \dotsc, x_{n+1}$ as variables with the recursion formula as equality constraints. then, minimize $x_{n+1}$. you can apply the usual theory and methods of nonlinear problems.

Comment: @user251257 I do not get it.Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

For a parametric recursion like $x_{n+1} = f(x_n, a)$ consider simply the following nonlinear constraint program
$$ \min x_{n+1} $$
such that
\begin{align}
  x_1 &= f(x_0, a), \\
  \vdots\; &= \quad\vdots \\
  x_{n+1} &= f(x_n, a), \\
\end{align}
where $a, x_1, \dotsc, x_{n+1}$ are the variables and $x_0$ some given constant.

It has the usual form of a nonlinear program. So, you can apply the known theories and methods.